# How to download a Subversion project from the web

Tags: windows, svn, download

I would to download the JNA subversion http://java.net/projects/jna/sources/svn/show/tags/3.2.7/jnalib/src?rev=1183

How can I do that? I use Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grab yourself a copy of [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and start with the link that says "Checkout URL" on that page, I'd guess.

Comment: It should be observed that you should not pick "Checkout URL" or "SVN repository URL" or anything like that on the TortoiseSVN site.  Instead, download and run the SVN installer, then use the brand-new option "SVN Checkout" on the shell right-click menu (in an empty directory) and feed it the URL for the JNA repository.